# Should I be worried about this HDD's health?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have multiple 2tb external drives all of which look like this (normal):

[image]

Then I have this new 4tb drive which looks like this after a week of usage:

[image]

SMART reports everything as ok. There are also no bad sectors.

Does the 4tb drive look like it may be defective?

Comment: healthy smart + no bad sectors = no worries as far as I go by

Comment: I'd totally agree with @adampski on this, Dingrite. As long as the SMART attributes don't show any errors, you shouldn't have anything to worry about. _(you can check those in the health tab of the diagnostic tool)_ *The best way to prevent any potential data loss is to keep your data backed up to several storage locations/drives!* Better safe than sorry, right? Keep an eye every once in awhile & make sure you use [WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics tool](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en) as well. It also monitors the health and SMART stats of your WD Drives. :) Hope this helps.